# Programmatically Add Site Template (.stp) to SharePoint

Tags: sharepoint, build-process, moss, sharepoint-2007

I would like to programmatically add a custom site template (.stp file) to a MOSS team site collection as part of my build process.  Can anyone point me towards the best way to do this?

Thanks, MagicAndi.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

A way of doing this with a feature would be to use the [File element](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms459213.aspx). STP files live in `/_catalogs/wt` so this type of feature will upload the file.

**Update:** More details in [Create Feature to Upload Site Template File (.stp) in MOSS](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1532642/create-feature-to-upload-site-template-file-stp-in-moss/1536817#1536817) but for completeness here is the elements.xml:

```
<Elements xmlns="http://schemas.microsoft.com/sharepoint/">
    <Module Name="TeamSiteTemplate" List="111" Url="_catalogs/wt">
        <File Url="TeamSiteTemplate.stp" Type="GhostableInLibrary">
            <Property Name="LanguageDisplay" Value="English" />
            <Property Name="Version" Value="3" />
        </File>
    </Module>
</Elements>
```

Comment: Hi Alex, I'm interested in pursuing this, but I have been unable to  get the site template appearing in the gallery when depolying the feature.  Could you provide a sample elements.xml file?  Thanks. +1

Answer (score 2):

It looks like a simple batch file calling the STSADM tool with the -AddTemplate parameter is one option for this.  The command is:

```
stsadm -o addtemplate -filename c:\template.stp -title "Template Title" -description "Template Description"
```

You can also delete an existing template using the command:

```
stsadm -o deletetemplate -title "Template title"
```

See this [article](http://technet.microsoft.com/en-us/library/cc261822.aspx) for further details

Answer (score 0):

to be more accurate: "stsadm -o addtemplate" adds the site template in the "**central template gallery**" not to a specific MOSS team site collection i.e. in the "**site collection template gallery**"; I think this can be a relevant difference in some (large) environment where could be advisable narrow the available template per sitecollection.

[Installing application templates for Windows SharePoint Services 3.0](http://technet.microsoft.com/en-us/library/cc288412%28v=office.12%29.aspx)