# Create Feature to Upload Site Template File (.stp) in MOSS

Tags: sharepoint, moss, sharepoint-2007

Following on from [this question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1530806/programmatically-add-site-template-stp-to-sharepoint), I have created a feature to upload an site template file as part of an automated build of a SharePoint site.  However, while the feature deploys the .stp file correctly to the hive, and the solution appears in the CAS | Operations | Solution Management page, the site template does not appear in the site template gallery as expected.  I have given the contents of the feature.xml and elements.xml files below; can anyone spot where I am going wrong?

**feature.xml**

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<Feature  Id="59627434-4B75-4f9c-B830-E6E34007DA70"
          Title=" Team Site Template"
          Description="UKTI Connect Team Site Template"
          Version="12.0.0.0"
          Hidden="FALSE"
          Scope="Web"
          DefaultResourceFile="core"
          xmlns="http://schemas.microsoft.com/sharepoint/">
  <ElementManifests>
    <ElementManifest Location="elements.xml"/>
    <ElementFile Location="TeamSiteTemplate.stp" />
  </ElementManifests>
</Feature>
```

**elements.xml**

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8" ?>
<Elements xmlns="http://schemas.microsoft.com/sharepoint/">
  <Module Name="TeamSiteTemplate" Url="_catalogs/wt" RootWebOnly="TRUE" >
      <File Url="TeamSiteTemplate.stp" Type="GhostableInLibrary" IgnoreIfAlreadyExists="FALSE">
        <Property Name="LanguageDisplay" Value="English" />
        <Property Name="Version" Value="3" />
      </File>
  </Module>
</Elements>
```

Thanks, MagicAndi

Answer (score 4, accepted):

This elements.xml works:

```
<Elements xmlns="http://schemas.microsoft.com/sharepoint/">
    <Module Name="TeamSiteTemplate" List="111" Url="_catalogs/wt">
        <File Url="TeamSiteTemplate.stp" Type="GhostableInLibrary">
            <Property Name="LanguageDisplay" Value="English" />
            <Property Name="Version" Value="3" />
        </File>
    </Module>
</Elements>
```

There are minor differences but the one that probably solves the problem is the inclusion of the `List` attribute.

To explain, in `%CommonProgramFiles%\Microsoft Shared\web server extensions\12\TEMPLATE\GLOBAL\XML\ONET.XML` see the line containing the words `sitetemplategalleryList`. This shows `Type="111"` which corresponds to `List="111"` in elements.xml.

Also note that I set the feature to Site scope as Colin suggested.

Comment: Alex, accepted as answer.  I had managed, with a colleague's help, to get the .wsp to deploy successfully by including an empty class file to update the .dll in the .wsp, even though the .dll itself was not deployed.

Comment: No problem! A feature receiver may have been another approach.

Comment: Is the STP file in the same folder as the elements file?

Comment: @Greg: The `Path` and `Url` attributes are a bit of a black art in my experience. But from reading this XML again I think it should work if the STP is in the same folder as `elements.xml`.

Answer (score 0):

Have you tried setting the scope of the feature to Site?

Comment: Colin, Thanks but I have already tried setting the scope to Site without success.  Thanks anyway.